# There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 21. XML Error

Tags: c#, xml

Getting an Error in my Code Here is the Loading Function:

This is the Error: There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 21

I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("text1.xml");
            XmlNodeType type;



 while (reader.Read())
            {
                type = reader.NodeType;

                if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "Title")
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        textBox12.Text = reader.Value;
                    }


                }

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    if (reader.Name == "Description")
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        textBox11.Text = reader.Value;
                    }

                }
            }
```

And this is the code that creates the XML File:

```
XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter("text1.xml", Encoding.UTF8);

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Tasks");

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Title");

            xWriter.WriteString(textBox1.Text); //  textbox.text 

            xWriter.WriteEndElement(); // title


            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Description");

            xWriter.WriteString(textBox2.Text); //  textbox.text 

            xWriter.WriteEndElement(); // description end 



            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Date");

            string val = "10/10/2010";
            dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(val);

            xWriter.WriteString(val); //  textbox.text 

            xWriter.WriteEndElement(); // description end 


            xWriter.WriteEndElement(); // close tasks



            xWriter.Close();
```

Comment: paste the generated xml?

Comment: <Title>test</Title><Description>test</Description><Date>10/10/2010</Date>

Comment: Yup, that has multiple root nodes (Title, Description, Date)

Comment: It seems like `Tasks` has never been written out

Comment: Your code executes perfectly in my tests.  I don't see what the problem is.  Your writer generated on my machine `<Tasks><Title>a test</Title><Description>test</Description><Date>10/10/2010</Date></Tasks>`

Comment: Its reading back in i get a problem

Answer (score 3):

All XML documents must have EXACTLY 1 root element, eg

```
<myroot>
   <foo>
   </foo>
</myroot>
```

You must be parsing a document with more than 1 root.  So text1.xml must have something like

```
<myroot>
   <foo>
   </foo>
</myroot>
<myotherroot>
   <bar>
   </bar>
</myotherroot>
```

Instead of having

```
xWriter.WriteStartElement("Tasks");
xWriter.WriteStartElement("Title");
```

you need to create Title as a subelement of Tasks (if that's what you intend the structure to be like).

Comment: So how would I add that to the XMLWriter section?

Comment: title needs to be a sub element of tasks

Answer (score 1):

Your XML generation looks fine. It creates only on root element . But I guess your intention was to have an XML storing multiple tasks. You have to create an XML similar to this:

```
<Tasks>  <!-- The actual root -->
    <Task>
        <Title></Title>
        <Description></Description>
        <Date></Date>
    </Task>
    <Task>
        <Title></Title>
        <Description></Description>
        <Date></Date>
    </Task>
    ...
</Tasks>
```

Comment: How Would I Amend XmlTextWriter  section to Suite this?

Comment: Now my structure is <Tasks><Title>steve<Description>campbell<Date>10/10/2010</Date></Description></Title></Tasks>

Comment: What version of .NET do you have?

Answer (score 1):

This code will read the XML you're writing:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("text1.xml");
var taskElement = doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Tasks");
if (taskElement != null)
{
    var taskElements = taskElement.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().ToList();
    var titleElement = taskElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Title");
    var descElement = taskElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Description");
    if (titleElement != null)
        textBox12.Text = titleElement.InnerText;
    if (descElement != null)
        textBox11.Text = descElement.InnerText;
}
```

But I think there's a problem with your writer. You must be writing more than you're telling us or you wouldn't have trouble with multiple root nodes. Any code you left out?